# How can i set password to nagios using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, nagios

I want to set the password for  nagios core using ansible playbook.
Manually doing , command to set the password is :

**sudo htpasswd -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin**

**New password:**

**Re-type new password:**

I want to set the same through ansible playbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the `htpasswd` module like this:

```
- name: Set password to nagios
  htpasswd:
    path: "/usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users"
    name: nagiosadmin
    password: "Very-Secure-Password"
    crypt_scheme: md5_crypt
```

**Note**: `passlib` must be install on host that executes module